# List of questions flashes briefly before showing a different set of questions, what's up with that?

Tags: support, questions, ignored-tags

I've noticed that when I view a list of questions on Stack Overflow, it will flash one set ever so briefly and then refresh to show a different set of questions.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have included tags in your list of ignored tags.

When loading up the questions page, the site will then check against your list of ignored and if you have selected **Hide Ignored Tags** in the **prefs** tab of your profile, it will remove them.

[image: hiding the tags from view]

The rest of the questions not affected will then bunch up to take up the remaining space.

This all happens client-side, not server side, which is why it will show all the questions for a brief period before vanishing.

Comment: It must be browser dependent then, because in FF3.0.15, when I add a few 'Ignored Tags' they're just greyed out, not removed. I have no 'Hide Ignored Tags' checkbox.

Comment: @random: I thought ignored tags causes the post to be greyed out?

    .tagged-ignored {
      background-color:#FFFFFF;
      opacity:0.5;
    }

Comment: ignored tags are hushed out. But if you check the box, they will disappear as well.

Comment: but ... *no checkbox* ?

Comment: @pavium Nothing here? http://stackoverflow.com/users/153545?tab=preferences#sort-top

Comment: Aah, thanks @random, I was looking under the Ignored Tags on http://stackoverflow.com/questions, but my profile page makes more sense, and I DO have a checkbox.