# Can you please get rid of the ignored questions hide flash using this technique?

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, ignored-tags

Related: [List of questions flashes briefly before showing a different set of questions, what's up with that?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30513/list-of-questions-flashes-briefly-before-showing-a-different-set-of-questions-wh)

Would it be a ton of overhead db-wise to add the `tagged-ignore-hidden` class to questions directly in the HTML source? This way they can instantly be hidden through:

```
<script>document.documentElement.className+= 'js';</script>
<style>html.js .tagged-ignore-hidden { display:none; }</style>
```

And this way, they don't briefly flash and then hide since that rule is immediately applied.

Or maybe if this adds a ton of overhead, have a autodisabled user preference that will do this server-side logic for certain users and not others, so "regulars" can have this added benefit of no flash hide?

Comment: What's the purpose of adding the `js` class?

Comment: To style certain components in a certain way if JS is enabled. If there is no JS, the `js` class wouldn't exist. The other bonus is any css rule containing it INSTANTLY hides the elements.

Comment: @meder Ah, makes sense

Comment: by "hides the elements" I obviously meant if it was display:none. This is a workaround for display:none through JS.

Comment: I believe the reason this is done pure client side is that the lists of questions are heavily cached so they're not unique per user/request.

Comment: This is essentially a different way of asking for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69874/with-the-so-homepage-redesign-can-server-side-highlighting-and-hiding-be-impleme